# Classpath is not working

Tags: java, ant, log4j, classpath, dom4j

I got source code from Hermes (hermes2_src_20100121). When I extracted it has about 10 folders which is separate projects.

```
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/ebxml-pkg
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/CorvusEbMS
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/Commons
Etc….

Each project has its own build script
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/ebxml-pkg/ant/build.xml
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/CorvusEbMS/ant/build.xml
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/Commons/ant/build.xml
Etc….
```

I need to build this 10 projects using the given ant scripts
when I run it the script fails and it gives compilation error
/myd1/Exetel/Hermes_SRC/ebxml-pkg/src/hk/hku/cecid/ebms/pkg/PKISignatureImpl.java:98: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
etc.....

Issue in this, log4j can’t be found(similary dom4J, Mail, etc….)

So I created folder in path “/myd1/exete/libs/” and added the required jar file there and set the CLASSPATH to this folder

```
CLASSPATH=/myd1/exete/libs/*
```

but still it gives the same error as the classpath is not working

I tried add CLASSPATH to ~/.bashhrc

```
CLASSPATH=/myd1/exete/libs/*
Export CLASSPATH
```

Add CLASSPATH to gedit /etc/environment
Env | grep CLASSPATH prints the correct path

The issue is when I run build script it still gives the same error as the classpath is not working

Answer (score 0):

You should either set classpath in ANT script:

```
<path id="common.classpath">
    <fileset dir="/myd1/exete/libs">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

or

Set `CLASSPATH` according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html:

> classpath1:classpath2 Class paths to the .jar, .zip or .class files.
>   Each classpath should end with a filename or directory depending on
>   what you are setting the class path to: For a .jar or .zip file that
>   contains .class files, the class path ends with the name of the .zip
>   or .jar file. For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path
>   ends with the directory that contains the .class files. For .class
>   files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that
>   contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package
>   name). Multiple path entries are separated by colons.
>
> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, you must include "." in the new settings.
>
> **Classpath entries that are neither directories nor archives (.zip or
>   .jar files) nor * are ignored.**

So you should try either:

```
CLASSPATH=/myd1/exete/libs/* 
or
CLASSPATH=/myd1/exete/libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your classpath as `CLASSPATH=/myd1/exete/libs/myjar.jar`

i.e. name your jar in the CLASSPATH!